# How to make drawable by layer-list

Tags: android, background, android-drawable, shapes, layer-list

I want to custom the edit text as below image
[image]

Currently, I am using a View with `width = 1dp` to trick for this case.
Actually it's a dirty approach so I want to make a drawable file by layer-list then add to background of EditText. It will look like:

```
______________ 

______________
```

On other hand, as Android Edit Text attribute we can use `drawableTop` and `drawableBottom` to add a divider ( just a `shape line` ) into.

My problem :
Method 1 ->  I can not create a background with top and bottom as a line
Method 2 ->  I have tried to use drawableTop but it does not show

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124919/can-i-draw-rectangle-in-xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44801662/7666442

Comment: this might be use full [https://android.jlelse.eu/simplifying-layouts-with-layer-list-drawables-2f750ea1504e]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="#a8a8a8" />
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
```